# Reward for running a full node on some blockchain?

Tags: synchronization, nodes, light-clients

For today, it takes a lot of time to install & sync a full node of the most popular blockchains - Bitcoin, Ethereum, etc. That's why so many people use only light wallets like Jaxx or Electrum. Which is not the blockchain way at all.

So the question is - can you name some protocols/consensus mechanism or anything else, which can solve this problem? Maybe it's possible to give a part of mining reward to the full nodes holders?

Comment: the whole cryptocurrency idea is only an experiment. Nobody knows yet if they are capable trillion dollar operations per day like forex does. And the theory is always different than reality.

Comment: @Nulik I would argue that some people know.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about this for a token concept.  Like, could one create a token that would be distributed randomly to anybody running a node and the length of time they run that node continuously.

For an actual blockchain, I think the short answer is no.  There is no "Proof of Running a Full Node" concept where a proper economic incentive could be established, but maybe someone will come up with it.  The one problem with rewarding full nodes for keeping a full account would be verifying that they are in fact running a full node.  How can the network in general be assured that someone is running a full node without checking all that data that is the full node?  Its easy to prove work was done to mine a block (you just check block hash), takes no time at all.  How much time and bandwith would it take to verify full nodes?  I have to imagine it would be a lot.

The real advantage to funning a full node is having a higher degree of security for transaction reliability.

On another note, in the future if there does emerge a "bandwith currency/token" there may be built in economic incentive to running a full node because light nodes would constantly have to be re-downloading the info for specific blocks with specific transactions over and over again.

Just my two cents.